# regex: Exclude only one URL of a range

Tags: regex

I have to block all the URL `*.company.com`, but keep `proxy.company.com` accessible. How could I do this with regex?

`[^proxy].company.com` does not work, I don't know why.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it for Google Analytics or .htaccess?

Comment: All the current answers use lookaheads and won't work in GA.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
^(?:(?!proxy)[a-z0-9-\.]+)\.company\.com
```

Your `[^proxy]` is a character set that matches any character that is not in the group. http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try `^(?!proxy)[^.]+\.company\.com$` using [Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/xU5aZ0/1)

Java Example:

```
    String regex = "^(?!proxy)[^.]+\\.company\\.com$";

    System.out.println("abc.company.com".matches(regex)); // true
    System.out.println("xyz.company.com".matches(regex)); // true
    System.out.println("proxy.company.com".matches(regex)); // false
```

Regex Explanation:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
    proxy                    'proxy'
  )                        end of look-ahead
  [^.]+                    any character except: '.' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))

  \.                       '.'
  company                  'company'
  \.                       '.'
  com                      'com'
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```